# Dynamic drop-down lists in Perl

Tags: php, javascript, perl, forms, dynamic

I'm new to web programming, but recently I've been given some scripting assignments as part of a summer internship. I've been working with Perl to create CGI scripts for my employer's internal website, mainly to be used by the developers there (non-critical).
The problem I am currently working on is generating reports based on a chosen directory on the server. The user should be able to choose an option from a drop-down box, and in turn, another drop-down box should have sub-options. These must be dynamic; if the first box is changed, the options in the second must be re-generated. Can Perl achieve this? Would PHP or JavaScript be a better tool to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Perl as well as anything else. You might profit from the [CGI::Ajax](http://p3rl.org/CGI%3a%3aAjax) module.